# How to open the share (windows 8.1 style) window from C#

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

I am trying to open the Share window from C# in an UWP project but I am not finding any examples of that...
  Is this possible by handling an event or something else ?

Comment: I think you should look harder, a quick google returns plenty of examples: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh871370.aspx

If it helps, you need to search for the 'Share charm' in C#/XAML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a detailed UWP sample app on GitHub

https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/ShareSource

The reference MSDN article about sharing and exchanging data

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh871373(v=win.10)

The guidelines for sharing content

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh465251

Answer (score 0):

This i was searching

```
DataTransferManager.ShowShareUI();
```

Thanks for your answers !